# Resolving citations within latex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I have a table in a manuscript that I writing that I need to send to the publisher as a .tex file. My table has references and to make it easier for my publisher I need to send them the .tex file without the `\cite` or in my case `\supercite` commands. What I need is a text macro to resolve my citations within the latex file. This table is a table included in my manuscript and the citations correspond to the references for my manuscript so I do not want to print a bilbliography only the citations as numbers. In the other words, given the files 'bib.bib' and 'example.tex' below I want to create 'filled-example.tex'. My table is very large with many multiple citations, so doing this manually would be very annoying.

bib.bib:

```
@article{Doe,
  title={Some Title},
  author={Doe, Jane},
  journal={My Journal},
  year={1984}
}
@article{Smith,
  title={My Title},
  author={Smith, Jane},
  journal={Some Journal},
  year={2017}
}
```

example.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=nature,backend=bibtex,sorting=none,maxnames=3,minnames=2]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    Hello & World \\
    First & X \supercite{Doe} \\
    Second & Y \supercite{Doe,Smith} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

filled-example.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=nature,backend=bibtex,sorting=none,maxnames=3,minnames=2]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    Hello & World \\
    First & X \textsuperscript{1} \\
    Second & Y \textsuperscript{1,2} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document structure isn't entirely clear, as it's lacking a `\printbibliography` statement. Assuming the absence of the `\printbibliography` statement is intentional, what are readers supposed to make of the `1` and `2` superscript-type citation call-outs? Please advise.

Comment: why don't they provide you with a template regarding their specifications?

Comment: @Mico I do not need a bibliography because this table is a part of a larger manuscript that will contain a bibliography. I need to send the table in a separate .tex file to the publisher and I want them to be able to process it properly. I have added this to my question.

Comment: you could look into the `.aux` file of the job that does contain the bibliography, and look for the lines in which the citation labels are defined.  then copy those lines into the preamble of your file and they should produce the correct references.  just make sure that the versions of the two source files are in synch.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's probably a better idea than what I'm trying to do. I guess do something along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's my suggestion.  look into the `.aux` file(s) of the job that contains the actual bibliography.  there should be some `\bibcite` lines; these will associate the labels used for the bib items to the assigned number or other reference string.

a (very) short example:

this file with one `\bibitem`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
some text with a citation for an author~\cite{cite:ex}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{cite:ex}
  An Author, Title, More

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

will (after a sufficient number of runs) produce this `.aux` file:

```
\relax 
\citation{cite:ex}
\bibstyle{plain}
\bibcite{cite:ex}{1}
```

the item of interest can be seen to have the number "1".  since a latex run picks up the references from an `.aux` file, copying the required `\bibcite` lines from there into the preamble of your "abbreviated" file should have the corresponding effect.

the format of the `\bibcite` lines is slightly different if `hyperref` is used.  make sure that the two jobs are compatible in that respect.